# How to retrive Value of selected GroupDropdown on controller side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

As I am new in MVC I dont know. How could I get the value of selected GroupDropdown on controller side. Here I am Binding by dropdown using json

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Property"))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
 <select id="GroupDropdown" onchange="CallSubGroup(this.value);" class="form-control"></select>
}
```

My controller side code is below still not getting the value.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(tblProperty property, FormCollection data)
    {
        foreach (var key in data.AllKeys)
        {
            var value = data[key];
            // etc.
        }
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the name attribute to select.

```
<select name="GroupDropdown" id="GroupDropdown" onchange="CallSubGroup(this.value);" class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC wants name values on the form elements to use as the key.

Html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Property"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
     <select name="GroupDropdown" id="GroupDropdown" onchange="CallSubGroup(this.value);" class="form-control"></select>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(tblProperty property, FormCollection data)
{
    string value = data["GroupDropdown"]
    //do things
    Return View();
}
```